# How to run multiple instances of the same service with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run 3 instances of docker image which runs on some port. I want the ports of all the 3 instances exposed to the host. I want to be able to control which of the host ports is mapped to the container.

First I tried creating 3 different services in docker-compose.yml. This worked but isn't preferable.

Second I create a single service in docker-compose.yml
Then I tried to control the exposed port via enviroment variables. But when I create the second container, docker removes the first container I created.

I cannot used the `scale` option because it maps the exposed ports to random port on host.

```
myservice:
    image: myimage:latest
    container_name: service-${PORT}
    volumes:
      - ${DIR}:/data
    ports:
      - "${PORT:-8011}:8011"
      - "${ADMINPORT:-8012}:8012"
```

Comment: Looks like you want to scale your app right ? Docker swarm or Kubernetes seem a better fit to your needs.

Comment: I removed the Java tag since it has nothing to do with the qestion

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4579

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can set the ports range to use with `scale` option of `compose`:

```
ports: - "8011-8013:8011"
```

start it:

```
docker-compose up --scale myservice=3
```

then the containers will use port `8011`, `8012` and `8013`